# OptimisticLockException in select query

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, jpa

Got an OptimisticLockException in select query

> javax.persistence.OptimisticLockException     at
>   org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.wrapStaleStateException(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1415)
>   [hibernate3.jar:3.6.10.Final]     at
>   org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1336)
>   [hibernate3.jar:3.6.10.Final]     at
>   org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1317)
>   [hibernate3.jar:3.6.10.Final]     at
>   org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl.***getResultList***(QueryImpl.java:255)
>   [hibernate3.jar:3.6.10.Final]

The query is a simple select query involving multiple entities and where clause like

> select distinct a.id ,b.type ... from table1 a ,table2 b ,table3
>   c...where b.id=a and c.id in...

It is known that OptimisticLockException occurs when we try to update a dirty entity ,but how can a select query cause this exception.Is there any possibilty or is this a bug ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most probably the select query is not the source of the exception but just the trigger.
Normally Hibernate will trigger flushes before relevant selects and thus if you made an update that causes an OptimisticLockException that exception will be thrown when the update is flushed.

Try a manual flush before executing the select query and you should see the exception there (you might have to set the flush mode to MANUAL though).

Comment: Thanks a lot,I was also thinking the same answer, Is this the only possibility for such a behaviour ?

Comment: @vignesh I'm not completely sure since there's are _always_ the possibility of a bug, but IMHO this is the most _probable_ reason.